# Transferring Zune Pass content from WP7 to WP8

Tags: music, xbox-music

Is there a way to get my WP8 phone to play music I had previously downloaded with a WP7 phone using a Zune pass?

The error message I get when I try to play the music is:

```
We are unable to confirm the media usage rights for this content
```

EDIT:
Here a few methods I've tried

1. [Synchronized my MS account (the one with the XBM pass) and restarted the phone](http://forums.wpcentral.com/xbox-music/207806-we-unable-confirm-media-usage-rights-content.html#post1821974)
2. [Tried waiting (only a few days so far)](http://forums.wpcentral.com/xbox-music/207806-2.htm#post1851005)
3. [Synched a Zune playlist and content, and restarted](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/why-wont-my-old-zune-pass-downloaded-music/7bb43169-f15c-4b16-864e-4cbebf82dba3?page=3)
4. Synched a Zune playlist without content, and restarted

The result is that a few artist I couldn't formerly play, I now can. However, the vast majority of my Zune pass content still gives me an error,

Comment: [Have you seen this thread?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpmusic/zune-playlists-not-syncing-to-my-wp8-lumia-920/f6dac957-ab82-42f9-aac3-3e7908325d87?page=5)

Comment: Also is your computer a Windows 8 or Windows 7 machine?

Comment: @karancan I only have a Win7 machine

Answer (score 1):

If the music has rights protection, then you probably didn't purchase those songs. However, if you still have a Zune pass subscription, you can download it to the new phone. In the media player, click the "..." on the bottom right of the screen and search for the song(s), once the song is selected - in a few seconds a "Download" option shows up.

You may need to go to the Zune Pass website if your old phone is still linked to the account, and remove it.

Comment: I would remove the content that you moved over to your phone first - it'll have the wrong authorization information on it, and that can cause a bit of confusion.